# Why an extra 'experience' from the experience?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [[5th last para on the page:]](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/euthanasia/infavour/infavour_1.shtml#h9) Being dead, versus not having been born
>
> Some people say that being dead is no different from not having been born yet, and nobody makes a fuss about the bad time they had before they were born.
>
> There is a big difference - even though being dead will be no different **as an experience from the experience** of not having yet been born.

Why's there an extra **experience**? The article contrasts 'being dead' with 'not having been born yet', so experience A against another experience B, NOT experience C from experience B?

Comment: Another way to put it would have been *the experience of being dead is not different from the experience of not having been born.*

Answer (score 1):

The author is trying to be precise.

In the statement "being dead will be no different *as an experience* from the experience of not having been born yet" the phrase "as an experience" is like the philosophical Latin "qua" -- *qua* experience.

There is a big difference between the two, in one case the person will have existed, but in the other, the person will never have existed, but in terms of what it feels like not to exist (an oxymoron, IMO) they are the same.